# Running maven project on eclipse kepler (4.3.1) for the first time

Tags: java, maven, webdriver

> AM new to Maven. I want to integrate my java project to Jenkins. Carried out research and discovered i can only do that using maven or Ant. I choose maven and managed to convert my existing java project on eclipse Kepler 4.3.1 to a maven project. Now i need to run a Maven build but i keep having COMPILATION ERRORS,
>   I need to get the maven working first before integrating to Jenkins i guess. Or am i omitting a step or adding step i do not need?. Had to take some errors out as it way out of my word limit
>   Have looked over all the Maven topic but non seems to help. Can anyone please help to with steps by steps procedure on how to get this done please. Below is my error: 
>   AM having difficulties posting the error. Wont accept my input

Comment: Sounds like it was a rough day. To insert code or error messages insert four spaces at the beginning of each line and leave a blank line at the top or bottom of the block. You need to provide more info if you expect help.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

First Check did u added all dependencies in pom.xm,l file...

right click on pom.xml, click on maven, select maven clean or maven install

so project will build, based on result we can fix it